# Supporting two kinds of user profiles

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have fully working code, however I'd like to make it nice. I've got these three models:

> 1. User (can have both or either one)
>      user can have one trucker
>      user can have one owner_trucker
> 2. Trucker
>      belongs to user
> 3. OwnerTrucker
>      belongs to user

I'm not the only one working in the app, but it starts to annoy me how everyone is solving the issue locally.

The problem is how to determine what the user is (a `trucker` or a `owner_trucker` or both). i.e if `user.trucker` is not nil, its a `trucker` etc.

So here are few examples from the application (various controllers), basically checking for the same thing but in a different way:

```
helper_method :profile_type_from_user
  def profile_type_from_user(user)
    return profile = user.trucker ? :trucker : :owner_trucker
  end
```

And then used in another controller like:

```
if profile_type_from_user(profile) == :trucker
else
end
```

Another example would be:

```
@profile = current_user.trucker ? current_user.trucker : current_user.owner_trucker
```

Checking if one or another:

```
current_user.trucker? && current_user.owner_trucker.nil?
```

It this refactorable?

Comment: Does the problem domain allow for a simplification of these roles? Are `owner_truckers` also a type of `trucker`? How is a `user` who is an `owner_trucker` different than if they were both a `trucker` and an `owner_trucker`? As it is seems like there are opportunities to remove these checks (or at least express them more meaningfully as part of the `User`) but without more understanding of the domain it's not clear what would be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your suspicion that the code is a "wet" is correct.  I would start moving these predicates into the model whenever they are:

- Used more than once, or
- Can make the code clearer by having a named predicate.

Consider replacing this:

```
helper_method :profile_type_from_user
  def profile_type_from_user(user)
    return profile = user.trucker ? :trucker : :owner_trucker
  end
```

With this:

```
class User
  ...
  def profile_type
    trucker ? :trucker : :owner_trucker
  end
  ...
end
```

Similarly, consider replacing this:

```
@profile = current_user.trucker ? current_user.trucker : current_user.owner_trucker
```

with:

```
class User
  ...
  def profile
    trucker || owner_trucker
  end
  ...
end

@profile = current_user.profile
```